# Prevent Automapper converting IEnumerable Property to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, kentico, kentico-kontent

I'm trying to map a Model to a ViewModel that has properties of types that inherit from IEnumerable. The properties are of the same type and name, but Automapper is converting the source to a Generic List and then failing to map to the destination.

These are the classes I'm trying to map:

```
BasicOverview
{
   public IRichTextContent Intro { get; set; }
   ...
}

BlogOverviewViewModel
{
   public IRichTextContent Intro { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

The following is third party code where the IRichTextContent type is defined:

```
//     Represents rich text content in a form of structured data
public interface IRichTextContent : IEnumerable<IRichTextBlock>, IEnumerable
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     List of rich text content blocks
    IEnumerable<IRichTextBlock> Blocks { get; set; }
}
```

My Automapper Profile:

```
public AutomapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BasicOverview, BlogListViewModel>();
        CreateMap<BasicOverview, ReviewListViewModel>();
        CreateMap<BasicOverview, BlogOverviewViewModel>();
    }
```

And this is the error I get:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KenticoCloud.Delivery.IRichTextBlock]' to type 'KenticoCloud.Delivery.IRichTextContent'.
>   lambda_method(Closure , BasicOverview , BlogOverviewViewModel , ResolutionContext )
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
>   BasicOverview -> BlogOverviewViewModel
>
> Type Map configuration:
>   BasicOverview -> BlogOverviewViewModel
>
> Destination Member:
>   Intro
>   lambda_method(Closure , BasicOverview , BlogOverviewViewModel , ResolutionContext )

I tried adding the following to my Automapper Profile:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<IRichTextBlock>, IRichTextContent>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Blocks, m => m.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Which produced the following error:

> TypeLoadException: Method 'GetEnumerator' in type 'Proxy_KenticoCloud.Delivery.IRichTextContent_12345678_' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abc123ef45' does not have an implementation.

Comment: You need to tell AM what's the concrete type for IRichTextContent.

Comment: Unfortunately, the concrete type is an internal class in the third party library.

Comment: OK, so maybe forget about AM for the moment. Try to understand how you would make the mapping by hand and then try to make that happen with AM.

Comment: It would just be IRichTextContent to IRichTextContent

Comment: So create a map that does that.

Comment: I can't because AutoMapper converts IRichTextContent to List<IRichTextBlock> which cannot be cast to IRichTextContent

Comment: ```CreateMap<IRichTextContent, IRichTextContent>().ConvertUsing(s=>s);```

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu could you add it as an answer?

Comment: I'm good. But feel free...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make the answer from [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu)'s comment more visible.

One of the solutions is to add following mapping to the Automapper profile:

```
CreateMap<IRichTextContent, IRichTextContent>().ConvertUsing(s=>s);
```